# Cross browser support for table cellspacing

Tags: html

I'm hoping someone can get me on the right path with this.

```
<table width="400" align="center" cellspacing="2" style="margin:auto" border="5" bordercolor="#669999" rules="NONE" frame="BOX">
```

This is producing the desired results in Firefox, but there is no cellspacing in IE or Opera (haven't checked any others). I've googled this and haven't been able to get an answer that works for me. I'm happy to accept 'operator error' and would love to be shown the proper way to have the browsers produce the same thing. 
I'll be grateful for any and all help. If there are errors in what I've posted please correct me, I would really like to learn how to do this.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It seems as the problem is with the `frame` attribute.
Why do you use this attribute at all, it seems as if you are doing what is done by default?

try removing it (completely) I know some old IE browsers don't deal with it correctly...
If you need to apply some border styling you better use CSS styling (from [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_frame.asp)):

> "For practical reasons, it may be better not to specify frames, and use CSS to apply border styles instead."
>   ...
>   "**Note**: IE9 displays this property correctly. Earlier versions of IE displays the borders on the cells within the table too (instead of on only the outside borders)."

Comment: Thanks. After poking around a bit @ W3Schools I got it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

After being pointed to W3Schools I was able to put this together:

```
<table width="400" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="1" style="margin:auto; border-spacing:1px 1px; border-collapse:separate; border:ridge 5px; border-color:#669999;" >
```

I ended up changing the cellspacing and border-spacing to 1px after seeing it in the browsers I tested (IE 9, Firefox 8.0 and Opera 11.52).
If there is a better way to do it I'd be interested to know. If my code has any mistakes in it, please let me know.
Cheers